# Standard resolution group homology

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I was reading Atiyah's and Wall's section on group cohomology (on Casslels-Frölich) and they went quite quickly on the homology section, and I wanted to understand if the following argument is correct.

We want to define the group homology of a group $G$ with values in a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module $M$ as the derived functor

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{H}^i(G, M) = \operatorname{Tor}_i^{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(\mathbb{Z}, M).
\end{equation}

This is a *balanced functor* which means we can calculate this from a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ (and not of $M$). For this consider the standard resolution

\begin{equation}
\dots \to P_i \to P_{i-1} \to \dots \to P \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0
\end{equation}

where $P_i = \mathbb{Z}[G^{i+1}]$ and the differentials are defined via the alternating sum 
$$d(\sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_i) = \sum_{k \in [n]}(-1)^k(\sigma_0, \dots, \hat\sigma_k, \dotsm \sigma_i).$$
Finally, we obtain the homology by applying the right exact functor $-\otimes_GM$ and take the homology of the complex.

So far so good. Now, the $P_i$ are actually free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules of rank $i+1$  right? So this means that
\begin{equation}
P_i \otimes_G M = M^{i+1}?
\end{equation}

If this is correct then the differential operator now how do we describe the differntial operators? Of course it's not the same formula as the above *mutatis mutandis* (I believe this would imply that the homology is always zero). I'm having trouble opening up the isomorphisms and writing it down, but the image of $M^2$ in $M$ needs to be $I_GM$ for this to work (where $I_G$ is the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z}$ sending every group element $\sigma  \mapsto 1$).

Comment: Well, $P_i$ is a free $\Bbb Z[G]$  module of rank $|G|^i$. I'm sure the Atiyah/Wall article does discuss chains/cycles/boundaries.

Comment: I believe you mean that $P_i$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of such rank, for $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ has rank $1$ over itself.
As for the second part, they describe it pretty thoroughly for cohomology, but for homology they just say "do what has to be made". At any rate I cannot find such description in terms of $A^i$ not here nor anywhere (but I'm speed reading formulas, so maybe I've missed something)

Comment: No, no, no. I meant exactly what I said.

Comment: Then I shall think about this better for a while

Comment: In cohomology, one has cochains which are maps from $G^i$ to $M$, but in homology one has chains which are maps from $G^i$ to $M$ **with finite support**. But in the homology case the boundary maps go in the other direction.

Comment: Aha! I see now, thank you (about the rank of the module)